# Order of a cyclic subgroup in G

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let G be a group where G = Z/4Z x Z/6Z.

I calculated the order of G to be 24.

Given the cyclic subgroup <(2,3)> in G. Can I say the order of this subgroup is also 24 given that a cyclic subgroup generates the whole group G.

Comment: No! $\vert (2,3) \vert =lcm\{\vert 2 \vert , \vert 3 \vert \}=lcm\{2,2\}=2$ where $2$ means $2+ 4 \Bbb Z $ and $3$ means $3+ 6 \Bbb Z $

Comment: Unless I'm misreading, you need to double check the definition of a cyclic subgroup. A cyclic subgroup is generated by a single element. A cyclic subgroup does not generally generate the whole group.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR how did you go from lcm{|2| , |3|} ={2,2}= 2 ?

Comment: perhaps easier to see: write out elements of your cycle subgroup and see when you get the identity